# Symfony 2 Routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I've got a problem with routing in my project.

I have 2 controllers, one is

> Domestos\TranslatingBundle\ProjectController.php

p

and second is

> Domestos\TranslatingBundle\LanguageController.php

Also i have routing set up with annotations.

routing.yml:

```
# import routes from a controller directory
translation:
    resource: "@DomestosTranslatingBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

ProjectController works great, router is working, great.

Problem is, that my LanguageController is not working. Controller should be done ok, but always when i call URL with route predefined in annotation, it throw error

> No route found for "GET /language/" 404 Not Found -
>   NotFoundHttpException 1 linked Exception:
>
> ```
> ResourceNotFoundException »
> ```

LanguageController.php looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Domestos\TranslatingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Domestos\TranslatingBundle\Entity\Language;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/language")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $languages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Language')->findAll();

        return $this->render('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Language:index.html.twig', array(
            'languages' => $languages,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/language//add")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        $language = new Language();

        $language->setTitle('Jazyk')
                 ->setCode('Skratka');
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($language)
                ->add('title', 'text')
                ->add('code', 'text')
                ->add('save', 'submit')
                ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($language);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Language:add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            )); 
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/language/edit/{id}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $language = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Language')->find($id);

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($language)
                ->add('title', 'text')
                ->add('code', 'text')
                ->add('save', 'submit')
                ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($language);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Language:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            )); 
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/language/delete/{id}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        $language = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Language')->find($id);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($language);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Language deleted: ' . $language->getCode());
    }

}
```

The question is, why is this controller not working? I need to finish project, and this is really annoying.

Comment: Double slash `@Route("/language//add")`?

Comment: Working. Thanks. Did not realize that typo...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try with

```
/**
 * @Route("/language")
 */
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/add")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
    // And so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping the tailing slash in:

```
resource: "@DomestosTranslatingBundle/Controller/"
```

to be:

```
resource: "@DomestosTranslatingBundle/Controller"
```

as seen as in: [**here**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)

If that does not work, try running:

```
php app/console router:debug
```

to see all the routes...

Answer (score 0):

Modify this

```
translation:
    resource: "@DomestosTranslatingBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

in

```
translation:
    resource: "@DomestosTranslatingBundle/Controller/LanguageController.php"
    type:     annotation
```